# Updating data with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have a simple form that contains the jquery UI date picker and basically when the date changes I want to refresh my data (go and get all records based on date).
However i have no idea how to do refresh the data?
So looking for advice and simple example if you could help please.

```
@model ViewModels.ScheduleMobileDisplay
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AppHomeLayout.Iphone.cshtml";

}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
{
    <div data-role="page" id="pageAccount">
        <link href="~/Content/CSS/jquery-ui-1.10.1.Redmond/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("#datepicker").datepicker(
                    {
                        showButtonPanel: true,
                        dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                            var date = $(this).val();
                            alert('I Need to refresh the data below' + date);
                        }
                    });
            });

        </script>
        <div data-role="content">

            <input type="text" id="datepicker"  placeholder="Select Date" />

            <ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
                <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">
                    @Model.AppointmentDate
                </li>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Appointments)
                {
                    <li data-theme="c">
                        <a href="/Schedule/MobileAppointmentEdit/@item.Id" data-transition="slide">
                            @item.StartTime @item.Name
                        </a>
                    </li>
                }

            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to make an [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) call to a webservice to get the data, then update your page in the ajax call's `success` callback.

```
$.ajax('www.mywebsite.com/myserviceurl', {
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: messageData,
    type: 'POST',
    timeout: 20000,
    success: function(data) {
        /* update page here */
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```